# Azure python SDK - Remove or deallocate VM from resource group

Tags: python, azure, azure-sdk-python

I want to deallocate a VM from a resource group using Azure sdk for python.
I have already created a VM using the sdk (compute_client.virtual_machines.create_or_update) but i am unable to find any specific method which would stop or deallocate a VM.

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refer to the doc of Azure SDK for Python and find the method `deallocate` of `VirtualMachinesOperations`, please see http://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/azure.mgmt.compute.operations.html#azure.mgmt.compute.operations.VirtualMachinesOperations.deallocate.

Here is code as reference.

```
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient, ComputeManagementClientConfiguration

credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
    client_id = '<client-id>',
    secret = '<key>',
    tenant = '<tenant-id>'
)

subscription_id = '<subscription-id>'

compute_config = ComputeManagementClientConfiguration(credentials, subscription_id, api_version='2015-05-01-preview')
compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(compute_config)
resource_group_name = '<resource-group>'
vm_name = '<vm-name>'
result = compute_client.virtual_machines.deallocate(resource_group_name, vm_name)
```

Comment: the reference page fails with 'permission denied'

Comment: working one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-compute/azure.mgmt.compute.v2019_03_01.operations.virtualmachinesoperations?view=azure-python#deallocate-resource-group-name--vm-name--custom-headers-none--raw-false--polling-true----operation-config-